# Trying to make a search feature in my JavaFX database

Tags: java, javafx

I am in the process of creating a JavaFX project that is connected to my SQL server to store movie data. it holds the title genre and release year. I want to make a search function so that when I type in the genre (Say its Action) only the action movies show up. Now, I am still fairly new to SQL and JavaFX so if someone is willing to help me I would greatly appreciate it.

This code produces no errors, it just simply does nothing. I have already made sure I set the action in scene builder.

Search Function:

```java
 @FXML
    private void searchMovies(ActionEvent event){
        String SQLSearch = "SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE genre = ?";

        try{
            Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(SQLSearch);
            while(rs.next()){
                this.mData.add(new movieData(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4)));
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.titleColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<movieData, String>("title"));
        this.starColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<movieData, String>("actor_actress"));
        this.directorColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<movieData, String>("genre"));
        this.releaseyearColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<movieData, String>("release_year"));

        this.movietable.setItems(null);
        this.movietable.setItems(this.mData);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "simply does nothing?" You get no results? The method is never called? Try using some `System.out.println()` statements in this method to ensure the query is correct and that results are actually being returned.

Comment: By "Simply does nothing" I mean it doesn't change the data at all. The method is being called, it just doesn't change the data in the table at all. I added a small bit of code to change the text of one of the text boxes to "Success" if the process was going through, and when I clicked the button it worked.

Comment: Then I recommend you study up on JavaFX properties. You should not be resetting the cell value factories each time the selection changes.

Comment: You need to use a `PreparedStatement` and not a `Statement` and you need to assign a value for the `?` place-holder via one of the `set...()` methods of interface `PreparedStatement`. And don't forget to close the `PreparedStetement` after retrieving all the query results.

Comment: I changed some code (found here: https://gist.github.com/KeyWeilder99/533b01cf7a9bef493c63247bdc500b3e ) yet it still does not load in the new data. It still gives no errors, and it is still giving output, it just doesn't change the data.

Comment: You got two choices. 1. Load all of the data from the database and use Java to filter the data. 2. run the correct queries from the database. I would suggest choosing one if you don't have a ton of data in the database.